# Top Right quater of screen unresponsive

Tags: lua, coronasdk

After programming some of my application I have noticed that for some reason the top right corner of my screen is completely unresponsive in both the corona simulator and on an actual android phone. Everywhere else works fine except this 1/4 of the screen. Even if i change the orientation of the screen in the build.settings file its always the top right corner that's the problem - which makes me think it a co-ordinates issue? 
Basically this means I cannot use the top right quarter of my screen for any event listeners (a problem since my app needs it...). 
I am using the 2013.12.7 version of the simulator and standard build.settings & config.lua files.

Has anyone come across this before? The problem is spread across multiple machines so I know its not an install issue. Any help Appreciated.

EDIT- Code requested is now below.

This is just one of my .lua files, it is the menu for the application. The top 2 buttons are unresponsive on their right halves.

```
module (..., package.seeall)

function new()

    local _H = display.contentHeight
    local _W = display.contentWidth

    local menuGroup = display.newGroup()

    local background = display.newImage("graphics/mainMenuBackground.png")
    background.x = _W/2
    background.y = _H/2

    local clefs = display.newImage("graphics/clefs.PNG")
    clefs.x = _W/2
    clefs.y = _H/4
    clefs.scene = "clefs"
    clefs.alpha = 0.8

    local stave = display.newImage("graphics/stave.PNG")
    stave.x = _W/2
    stave.y = _H/2.5
    stave.scene = "stave"
    stave.alpha = 0.8

    local notes = display.newImage("graphics/notes.PNG")
    notes.x = _W/2
    notes.y = _H/1.8
    notes.scene = "notes"
    notes.alpha = 0.8

    local timeSignatures = display.newImage("graphics/timeSignatures.PNG")
    timeSignatures.x = _W/2
    timeSignatures.y = _H*0.7
    timeSignatures.scene = "timeSignatures"
    timeSignatures.alpha = 0.8

    local howToWrite = display.newImage("graphics/howToWrite.PNG")
    howToWrite.x = _W/2
    howToWrite.y = _H*0.85
    howToWrite.scene = "howToWrite"
    howToWrite.alpha = 0.8


    menuGroup:insert(background)
    menuGroup:insert(stave)
    menuGroup:insert(clefs)
    menuGroup:insert(notes)
    menuGroup:insert(timeSignatures)
    menuGroup:insert(howToWrite)

    stave:addEventListener("touch", changeScene)
    clefs:addEventListener("touch", changeScene)
    notes:addEventListener("touch", changeScene)
    timeSignatures:addEventListener("touch", changeScene)
    howToWrite:addEventListener("touch", changeScene)

    return menuGroup

end
```

Comment: Is the position is covered with any UI elements(such as scrollview or something)? Can u post your code?

Comment: I have put the code into my post. and no, there are no scrollviews anywhere in my project

Comment: It seems like there is no display object ath the top right corner, and you haven't assigned any eventListeners for 'background'. Then how do you suppose to get a call back on touching that area? Try to add an eventListener to 'background' and check whethr it is responding to touch.

Comment: Hi, i posted a similar query on the corona forums, was solved by one of the devs, from what i could gather from them its due to the fact im using the director class, and the fact its not fully supported on graphics 2.0, i switched to storyboard and it all works fine now, thanks for the help though.